# How can i make the posts individual to each users and login process needed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to rails and I am reading http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html. There is an example where the data can be stored, edited and deleted but any user can store, edit and delete. I am looking to store data specific to each user and they should see only their data and not others. I want a login process where the user should login and store his/her own data and have the ability to modify or delete.

Also, I want this to be an api so that it can be used by applications. How can I do this? Are there any examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a lot you are asking at once. There is too much to explain in detail here, so I will just point you in the right direction. I will assume that you can follow the links, and read the documentation yourself. For more details on Ruby on Rails, read the [Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org).

Some of the functionality you want can be handled by existing Ruby Gems:

To handle user login and registration (authentication), [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) is recommended as the most actively maintained gem currently.

To handle user abilities and permissions (authorization), you can use [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan).

To describe the permissions when using CanCan, in the `Ability` model, you just say:

```
def initialize(user)
  can :manage, Data, :owner_id => user.id
end
```

More information can be found on the [CanCan wiki](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki). You will need to add an `owner_id` column in each of your `Data` models. This should be easy, just define an association on the `Data` model.

```
class Data < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => :User
end
```

And also [migrate your database](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html).